# pass values between methods in shared libraries in Jenkins Templating Engine

Tags: jenkins, shared-libraries, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-template-engine

I am trying out Jenkins templating Engine, my governance Tier has the following `Jenkinsfile`

```
node("Build-Node") {
def artifactVersion
checkout()
build()
sourceArtifact = docker_build()
push(sourceArtifact)
}
```

My shared library has the following structure

```
shared-library
|
|--docker
|   |--steps
|       |--docker_build.groovy
|       |--push.groovy
|--maven
|   |--steps
|        |--build.groovy
|--npm
|   |--steps
|        |--build.groovy
```

In my client side, pipeline_config.groovy has the following -

```
libraries {
   docker {
   url = "REGISTRY_URL"
   credentials = "REGISTRY_CREDENTIALS"
   @override sourceArtifact= "" //this has to be overriden in Jenkinsfile and new value fetched should be passed to the push() method.
    //more docker configuration
   }
}
```

My `docker.build()` method looks like this -

```
def call() {
     //do docker build 
     return sourceArtefact 
}
```

I have been getting an error saying that the call method is not found in push.groovy.
How can I correctly pass values between two different methods in a shared libary in JTE?

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: It might come from this, but it might also be a typo. Are the folders directly in the shared library or is this the content of your src folder?

Comment: they are directly under the shared library and not in the src folder. I followed the steps as per the documentation https://boozallen.github.io/sdp-docs/jte/2.2.2/upgrade-2.0.html

Comment: Ok my bad I thought you were using the [Jenkins Shared Library plug-in](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/). Unfortunately I can't help you on this one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i wouldn't recommend creating tight couplings between the steps of your template.

You want your steps to be as self-contained as possible to ensure you can swap between implementations freely.

If you create a step that takes input variables, you're creating a "contract" that every implementation of that step that may be used in the template is going to have the same method signatures.

If you always know you're going to push the container image after it's built, you should do that within the build step.

that being said - your question has nothing to do with the error you're saying you're receiving. It sounds like your push method doesn't accept an input parameter for the source artifact - so the pipeline is failing because it can't find a call method with zero input parameters.